# How can I visualize Random Forest Model in Python?

Tags: python, classification, random-forest, ensemble-learning, visualize

I developed a Random Forest Classifier in Python. Also, I used GridSearch method. Now, how can I visualize these tree ?

```
   # RandomForest 

RFC = RandomForestClassifier()

param_grid = {
              "max_depth": [4,5,7,8,10],
              "max_features": [1, 3, 10],
              "min_samples_leaf": [1, 3, 10],
              "bootstrap": [False],
              "n_estimators" :[80,100,120,150],
              "criterion": ["gini"]
}


gs_RFC = GridSearchCV(RFC,param_grid = param_grid, cv=kfold, scoring="f1", n_jobs= 4, verbose = 1)

gs_RFC.fit(X_train_smo,y_train_smo)
```

Comment: Are you asking for a visualization tool in python? a technique?
Is that your complete code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to visualize each tree or the ensemble ?

Comment: No, I just want to visualize the final (ensemble) tree.